# How to define a abstract in routeprovider?

Tags: angularjs

I want to define a abstract in route provider as we can define it in a state provider to for parent.

```
.when('/home', {
  title: 'home',
  templateUrl : 'templates/home.html',
  controller  : 'HomeController'
  })



.when('/about', {
  title: 'about',
  templateUrl : 'templates/about.html',
  controller  : 'AboutController'
 })
```

i want to define a (/home) as abstract or is the any way to use a HomeController as a global for entire application.

My controller is :

```
.controller('HomeCtrl', function($scope, $http, oliveService, $location, $routeParams) {

    console.log('home ctrl');

    $scope.about_info = function(){
    console.log('this is about info');
}
})

.controller('AboutCtrl', function($scope, $http, oliveService, $location, $routeParams) {

    console.log('about ctrl');

    $scope.about_info = function();
})
```

Answer (score 1):

> is the any way to use a HomeController as a global for entire application?

Yes,you can.

consider the index template :

HTML :

```
<body ng-view>

   <div  ng-controller="globalCtrl">

   </div>
</body>
```

and define your controller as usual.

Comment: Thanks for helping but but when i am trying to implement this then it returns to me Type error : Cannot read property 'childNodes' of undefined

Comment: Its look like related to your custom directive or jquery related script.Please click on error in console and check the source code

Answer (score 0):

For the ngRoute router there are no abstract states like for uiRouter. Just attach a Controller to the Body Tag for example.